# Send form from controller to view using datatables in laravel 5.1

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.1, formhelper

This is my code :

```
public function getRolesData()
    {
        $roles = Role::All();
        return Datatables::of($roles)      
            ->addColumn('action', function ($role) {
                return "{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('admin.role.destroy',".$role->id."))) !!}
                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        ";
                })            
                ->make(true);
    }
```

In 'action' column in view, I get the same code :

```
{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('admin.role.destroy',1))) !!} {!! Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!} {!! Form::close() !!}
```

No submit button is appeared ! what's the mistake in my code ?

Comment: It doesn't work :/
In fact when I use the basic form of forms like this :

...  
            ->addColumn('action', function ($role) {
                return "<form action='role/destroy/".$role->id."' method='Post'>                                               
                     ...   
                       </form> "; })            

It works but an other error appears :
 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you're using blade sintax which won't work inside your controller as it's not a blade file.

Try:

```
return  \Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('admin.role.destroy',".$role->id."))) .
        \Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) .
        \Form::close();
```

Alternatively, you could move the form in to a `blade` file

e.g. `views/admin/role/partials/datatables-form.blade.php` (or wherever makes sense for your app) and just return that view file instead.

i.e.

```
return view('admin.role.partials.datatables-form', compact('role'))
```

**admin/role/partials/datatables-form.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('admin.role.destroy',".$role->id."))) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot :)))
You missed render() method ^^
return view('admin.role.partials.datatables-form', compact('role'))->render()